# Split values by tag <br> HtmlAgility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I get the value from ChildNode.InnerHtml as

```
20th Aug 2013<br>Ojas Systems <br> Pune <br> Software
```

How to split the values from generated InnerHtml by HtmlAgilty.
I tried converting InnerHtml to string, but it throws an error

> No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

may be because of unclosed html tags but then what could be the solution
Below is the returned InnerHtml

```
<a href="http://jobs.monsterindia.com/details/13826093.html?sig=js-1- 4f08ba3c3102de443076cfb01e15745e-1&from=" target="_blank" id="link13826093">.Net java </a>, 20th Aug 2013<br>Ojas Systems Private Limited<br> Pune, 0-0 years: Looking for freshers who is trained in .Net Java.The location will be Pune.Preferably passed in 2012-2013. <br><a href="javascript:findSimilar(13826093)">Similar Jobs</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://jobsearch.monsterindia.com/searchresult.html?cid=117314;lan=1">All Jobs by this Recruiter</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:openSocialTwist({EXP:'Experience - 0 to 0 years',LINK:'http://jobs.monsterindia.com/details/13826093.html',COMP:'Company Name - Ojas Systems Private Limited',LOC:'Location - Pune',ROLE:'',KWD:'Key skills - .net java',TTL:'Job Title - .Net java '})">Share this job</a>
```

Comment: show us the code you are trying..and also the error

Answer (score 3):

Taken form [Here](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10403091/how-t-split-string-with-br-.aspx)  worked for me

```
string str = "hai<br/>how<br/>Are<br/>you";

            string[] delim = { "<br/>" };

            string[] spltd = str.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you able to retrieve ChildNode.InnerHtml you also should be able to save it as a string:

```
string inner_html = ChildNode.InnerHtml.ToString();
```

You could replace `<br>` with "/" or some other char (`inner_html .replace("<br>,"/")`) and then use simple string split on "/" char

**EDIT**:

If the innerhtml will always be in the same format you could go with something like this

```
string[] delimiter = new string[] {"<br>"};
string inner_html = ChildNode.InnerHtml.ToString();
int i = inner_html.IndexOf("</a>");
if( i!=-1)
{
   int j = inner_html.IndexOf("<a", i + 4);
   if (j != -1)
   {

      string yourStr = inner_html.Substring(i + 4,j);
      string[] splitedStr = yourStr.split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
   }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check the line it shows InnerHtml that I get.

Comment: Try to use InnerText instead of InnerHtml

Comment: but I need to split the text by each <br> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "20th Aug 2013<br>Ojas Systems <br> Pune <br> Software";
string[] result = input.Split(new string[]{"<br>"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Output

```
20th Aug 2013 
Ojas Systems  
 Pune  
 Software
```

Comment: It's still throwing an error-- No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

Comment: first line converting to string.

Comment: please refer this , I have posted the code here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902402/how-to-convert-htmlagilitys-innerhtml-to-string